# Media Sharing protocol

Tags: file-sharing

I'm using a vanilla Debian 8 install with GNOME and in the Settings tool there is a Sharing icon.  Clicking it gives three options:

- Personal File Sharing (dav)
- Screen Sharing (vnc)
- Media Sharing (???)

Hopefully if someone can identify the protocol for Media Sharing, I can figure out how to connect to it across my home network.  Is it samba? NFS?  I don't necessarily have clients for many suspect protocols handy, so trying them all would be a nuisance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the Gnome Wiki, and knowing that it is a popular protocol for sharing music and video Streams, the Share option from gnome uses `dlna`/`UPnP`. Quoting Gnome Wiki:

> **Share your music, photos and videos**
>
> You can browse, search and play the media on your computer using a
>   UPnP or DLNA enabled device such as a phone, TV or game console.
>   Configure Media Sharing to allow these devices to access the folders
>   containing your music, photos and videos.

Having an equipment that is "DLNA Ready" like a smarttv or even a media player that can listen to dlna, and be placed on the same network is enough to receive the sharing stream.

> Depending on the manufacturer, the product may use a branded version
>   of DLNA such as SmartShare (LG), SimplyShare (Philips), or AllShare
>   (Samsung), but rest assured it’s all the same technology and it will
>   all interoperate.

From [getting started with DLNA](http://www.techhive.com/article/2020825/how-to-get-started-with-dlna.html).

**Keeping the answer short**: It will map a folder of your computer that has media in, and create some sort of "sharing" through `dlna`. You will need to have at the other side, a client(hardware or software) that can handle dlna streams. The same dlna server setup can be created with [`minidlna`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ReadyMedia). Some servers can "send" media stream to a waiting client, and not only provide a share.

**Related Links:**

- [Sharing Settings - Gnome Help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/sharing-media.html.nl)
- [DLNA - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance)